# 2 Merge Statements inside a Procedure PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, keyword

I am trying to use 2 Merge Statements inside Procedure.
The one should delete the rows that are not in the other table.

The other one should insert the ones that are not in the table.

In this Case i am getting the error that a keyword is missing.

```
create or replace noneditionable procedure merge_test
as
BEGIN

Execute immediate 'alter table
   table person
DISABLE constraint
FK_FGH_ID ';


Merge into (select distinct * from 
person_test) t1
Using (select * from person) p1
On (p1.person_id = t1.person_id)
When not matched then
DELETE
FROM
    person
WHERE
    Person_id = p1.person_id;
COMMIT;

Merge into person p
USING (select distinct * from 
person_test) t
On (t.person_id = p.person_id)
When not matched then
Insert(person_id,vorname, nachname, mobil, telefon, fax, e_mail, fgh_id)
values(t.person_id, t.vorname, t.nachname, t.mobil, t.telefon, t.fax, t.e_mail, t.fgh_id);
COMMIT;

Execute immediate 'alter table
   person
ENABLE constraint
   FK_FGH_ID ';


End merge_test;
```

The Keyword is missing error is at 'WHEN NOT MATCHED' in the first Merge.
The other Queston is if it is even possible to have 2 Merge Statements inside one procedure.

Comment: you should absolutely avoid this terrible "`select *`" thing. Replace it by the explicit column names.

Comment: DELETE in a MERGE statement only applies to the **merged** table, that is we can only call it from the WHEN MATCHED branch. That whole first MERGE statement is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, having two `MERGE` statements inside a procedure is definitely possible, but why are you using them in this scenario? Just use a simple `DELETE` then `INSERT` statement similar to the one below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE merge_test
AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table person DISABLE constraint FK_FGH_ID';

    DELETE FROM person
          WHERE person_id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM person_test);

    INSERT INTO person (person_id,
                        vorname,
                        nachname,
                        mobil,
                        telefon,
                        fax,
                        e_mail,
                        fgh_id)
        SELECT person_id,
               vorname,
               nachname,
               mobil,
               telefon,
               fax,
               e_mail,
               fgh_id
          FROM person_test
         WHERE person_id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM person);

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table person ENABLE constraint FK_FGH_ID';
END merge_test;
```

Comment: The Seeker uses DISTINCT when they query from `person_test`. Assuming they have a valid reason for doing so, you should have included it in your INSERT ... SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using more than one `MERGE` Statement within a stored procedure is not problem.

You can still use the first `MERGE` Statement by converting the related part

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
DELETE FROM person
WHERE Person_id = p1.person_id
```

to :

```
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1.person_id = p1.person_id 
                   DELETE WHERE person_id = p1.person_id
```

but a `DELETE` Statement cannot take place following `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN`

*Btw, it's not a good practice two have more than one `COMMIT` within a single transaction, rather keep the last one only.*

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
create or replace noneditionable procedure merge_test
IS

BEGIN

    Execute immediate 'alter table person DISABLE constraint FK_FGH_ID ';

    Merge into person_test t1
    Using (select * from person) p1
    On (t1.person_id = p1.person_id)
    when matched then 
         update set t1.Person_id = t1.Person_id
             where t1.Person_id = p1.person_id
         delete 
             where t1.Person_id = p1.person_id;

    COMMIT;
    
    Merge into person p
    USING (select * from person_test) t
    On (t.person_id = p.person_id)
    When not matched then
        Insert(person_id,vorname, nachname, mobil, telefon, fax, e_mail, fgh_id)
        values(t.person_id, t.vorname, t.nachname, t.mobil, t.telefon, t.fax, t.e_mail, t.fgh_id);
    
    COMMIT;
    
    Execute immediate 'alter table person ENABLE constraint FK_FGH_ID ';

End merge_test;
/
```

Please note that you have an error in your first Execute immediate statement. It should be :

```
Execute immediate 'alter table person DISABLE constraint FK_FGH_ID ';
```